# How to list the total hours spent on each project (attribute) in ASSIGNMENT TABLE in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have one ASSIGNMENT table that includes attributes (ID, FirstName, LastName, Project, Hours). I created my table and inserted values inside. However, I am unable to list the total hours spent on each project. I have multiple Projects, some that are repeated multiple times.

For example, Project '333' is repeated many times. I want to list the total hours spent on each project.

```
SELECT sum( Hours) as total_hours
FROM ASSIGNMENT
WHERE Project = Project;
```

and I got Total_hours 165, but not the total hours of each project

Comment: Check out the GROUP BY clause.  It allows for aggregation over a nominated column (or columns).

Answer (score 0):

Use `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT sum( Hours) as total_hours
FROM ASSIGNMENT
WHERE Project = Project
GROUP BY Project
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use group by. Your query will be:

```
SELECT sum(Hours) as total_hours
FROM ASSIGNMENT
WHERE Project = Project group by Project ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT(Project),SUM(Hours) AS TimeSpent
FROM ASSIGNMENT
GROUP BY Project;
```